# Using Forms after migrating from playframework 2.0 to 2.1 RC2 (java)

Tags: migration, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I have updated my controllers with to use play.data.Form.form() method instead of Controller.form(). When I try to run my application I get errors like:

error: method render in class create_user cannot be applied to given types;

```
return ok(create_user.render("", Form.form(CreateUserInfo.class), creator.get()));
```

required: String, play.api.data.Form, User
found: String, play.data.Form, User

It looks like the my templates expect to get play.api.data.Form instead of play.data.Form. Is there suppost to be any implicit conversion or should I update my templates to use play.data.Form?

If I'm using play.data.Form in my templates I am missing out on some of the features of play.api.data.Form, like the ability to request parameters through the apply method ( ex: createUserForm("username") )

Comment: I've just checked the API docs for Play 2.1 RC2, and I cannot find a `play.data.Form` class. I think I remember that some packages were moved to `play.api.*`, but I cannot remember where and I'm not able to find it now. What happens if you just use the `play.api.data.Form` everywhere you've used `play.data.Form`?

Comment: It seems like the API docs are missing some parts at the moment,play.data.Form is a part of 2.1 (I have checked the source).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was provided by Guillaume Bort at the [playframework google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/octCwQ4_hmI).

I forgot to add javaCore as a dependency for my application after updating Build.scala. You have to explicitly add javaCore as a dependency in 2.1.

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
      javaCore
)
```

And remember to start using play.Project instead of PlayProject:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here
)
```